# Can "there" be a coreference?

Tags: expressions

If I understand correctly, "there" can be a noun and thus be a subject or object. I therefore assume that it can also be a coreference like in the following example:

> *Slurpilicious is a fancy restaurant. I just had dinner there.*

However, all the examples for coreferences mostly use persons and pronouns etc. as examples. I also assume that there's no difference to:

> *Slurpilicious is a fancy restaurant. I just had dinner at that place.*

where "that place" is a coreference to Slurpilicious.

Comment: In the first sentence, [*there*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there) is an adverb, not a noun. If it were a noun, you'd have to be able to say *I just had dinner at there*, which you can't.

Comment: @JasonBassford that makes sense, thanks! It seems to be used as an pronominal adverb in that case, representing "in/at that place". So I assume that is a coreference.